# Unable to UPDATE mysql table from a function, although successful query response

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am using PHPMyAdmin for my database. When a button on my html page is clicked, the following is executed:

```
var stopID = 10; // Sample
var stopPOV = "129.29,158.58"; // Sample

$.ajax({
    url: "getFromDB.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: "setStopPOV",
        stopID : stopID,
        stopPOV : stopPOV
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);
    }
});
```

My getFromDB.php is such:

```
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    require_once('db_functions.php');

    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];

        switch ($action) {
            case "setStopPOV":
                $stopID = $_POST['stopID'];
                $stopPOV = $_POST['stopPOV'];

                setStopPOV($stopID, $stopPOV);
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Finally, setStopPOV(...) function inside db_functions.php is as below:

```
<?php
    function setStopPOV($stopID, $stopPOV) {
        global $dbc;        // Set in connect.php

        $query  = "UPDATE stop ";
        $query .= "SET STOP_POV = '{$stopPOV}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE STOP_ID = '{$stopID}'";

        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        if ($result) {
            file_put_contents('function_result.txt', "Record updated successfully" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            file_put_contents('function_result.txt', "Error updating record" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
?>
```

This outputs 'Record updated successfully' info the txt file, but nothing is updated in the database.

However, if getFromDB.php is like this:

```
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    require_once('db_functions.php');

    // NEW CODE ADDED START
    $id = 10;
    $pov = "129.29,158.58";

    $qry  = "UPDATE stop ";
    $qry .= "SET STOP_POV = '{$pov}' ";
    $qry .= "WHERE STOPID = '{$id}'";

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $qry) or die("Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

    if ($result) {
        file_put_contents('function_result.txt', "Record updated successfully" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        file_put_contents('function_result.txt', "Error updating record" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
    // NEW CODE ADDED FINISH

    ...

    // The rest is previous code as shown above
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];

        switch($action) {
            // Code
        }
    }
?>
```

And I go to the page directly (i.e. localhost/getFromDB.php), The txt file has 'Record updated successfully' AND the database is updated!

It is important to note, that my db_functions.php contains other functions which retrieve info from the DB and they work as expected. For example, this is one such function in the db_functions.php

```
function getRouteList() {
    global $dbc;

    $query  = "SELECT RTE_NAME, TRAV_DIR ";
    $query .= "FROM route";

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($dbc));

    // Do whatever I want with the retrieved data
}
```

I have tried everything to get the update to work, but I haven't been able to. What am I missing?

Comment: As another debug step, what happens if in your original getFromDB.php file, you change the line `setStopPOV($stopID, $stopPOV);` to `setStopPOV(10, "129.29,158.58");` ? This step will help to determine if the problem is related to passing the parameters correctly to getFromDB.php, or if the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @BenHolness The passed parameters are being being received/parsed by the setStopPOV function with same result. 'Record updated successfully' and no change in DB.

Comment: Is your $_POST actually containing what you expect it to? Have you tried dumping it? Debugging 101.

Comment: @purpleninja Yes. My $_POST has what I expect. I have tried outputting them to the txt file (in switch case as well as inside setStopPOV) and the passed and received parameters match.

Comment: If you add the line `$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);` after the query and record `$affected_rows` in `function_result.txt`, how many rows does it say were affected? Can you also record the value of `$query` in  `function_result.txt` for both versions of getFromDB.php and compare the differences?

Comment: @BenHolness Thanks Ben! It was a very small error in the query. The one that did not work had 'STOP_ID' while the one that was working had 'STOPID'. So now it is working! I must have missed that when I compared the queries before asking on SO. Thanks again! You want to post your last comment (or pointing out the error) as a response so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

If you add the line `$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);` after the query and record `$affected_rows` in `function_result.txt`, how many rows does it say were affected? Can you also record the value of `$query` in `function_result.txt` for both versions of getFromDB.php and compare the differences?

The answer was found - in one instance a database variable was named `STOPID` in the other, it was `STOP_ID`. By OP comparing the queries, they found the difference and resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Can't believe I let that one slip, but it's always the little things!